# Unable to get the getElementById from a webpage

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to access a webpage and update the user name and password, but unable to get the getElementById

I tried the similar code with google and yahoo, they work perfectly. Below is the code I'm using

```
Sub Openurl()

Dim IE As Object
Dim IEPage As Object
Dim IEPageElement As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate URL

' The below piece of code also does not work

Do Until IE.readyState = 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE in early binding
DoEvents
Loop


Set IEPage = IE.Document

Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById(cwsUID)
If Not IEPageElement Is Nothing Then


IEPageElement.Value = UserName

Set IEPageElement = Nothing

Else

MsgBox "Coould not find the '" & UNElementID & "' element ID on the page!", vbCritical, "Element ID Error"

Exit Sub

End If


End Sub
```

---

Kindly let me know if there is something wrong with this code.
Below is the source code

```
input type="text" name="cwsUID" id="cwsUID" value="" placeholder="CWS ID" autocomplete="off" autofocus=autofocus
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not VB-expert, I believe you have to use quotes:
`IEPage.getElementById("cwsUID")`
as `cwsUID` is not a variable name but id.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the GetElementID by using

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: Now I am trying to click on a Javascript <a> tag but unable to execute, Can anyone tell how to execute this. Below is the source code.                              <UL>
 <LI> 


                             
                             

  <A NAME ="#TEBE45150001i0" 
HREF="javascript:onSelect('TEBE45150001','IETIT0','i0',0,'E');">
    <FONT SIZE=2 FACE="Geneva,Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif" >
    PRODUCT SUPPORT PROGRAM FOR REPLACING NEEDLE VALVE SUPPLY TUBES ON CERTAIN G3606B, G3608B, AND G3612B PETROLEUM ENGINES 08/07/2016</font></A><P>

 </LI>
 </UL>

Comment: Can anyone try to assist me with this issue?